# Retrieving all elements with at least two children of specific type with xml.etree.Elementree in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am using `xml.etree.Elementree` to retrieve all items `<a>` with at least two childrens `<b>`. I was trying to do it with `findall` method, but it seems there is no option to check this requirement.

as an example, if I have this file:

```
<main>
  <a>
    <b>...</b>
    <b>...</b>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>...</b>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>...</b>
    <b>...</b>
    <b>...</b>
    <b>...</b>
  </a>
</main>
```

I want to retrieve the first and third `<a>` element.

Is there a way to perform this filtering?

Comment: at least, you should post an example xml fragment and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `lxml.etree.xpath()` method:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('yourfile.xml')
nodes = tree.xpath('/main/a[count(./b) > 1]')
for a in nodes:
    print(list(a))  # getting child nodes of the current <a> node
```

The output (consecutively: `a` node with 2 `b` childs and `a` node with 4 `b` childs):

```
[<Element b at 0x1577d08>, <Element b at 0x1577d48>]
[<Element b at 0x1577d48>, <Element b at 0x1577d88>, <Element b at 0x1577dc8>, <Element b at 0x1577e08>]
```